# Warning: Undefined array key even when I'm not using array

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following code:

```
<form action="calculator.php" method="get">
  <label for="age">Enter your age</label>
  <input type="number" id="age" name="age">

  <br>
  <label for="height">Enter your height</label>
  <input type="number" id="height" name="height">
  <br>

  <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$age = $_GET["age"];
$height = $_GET["height"];

if (isset($age) && isset($height)) {
  echo ($age + $height);
}
?>
```

This gives me the warnings: **Warning: Undefined array key "age" in (file location)** and **Undefined array key "height" in (file location).**

As you can see I'm not using arrays. I googled this and tried putting the echo statement inside an if ( isset() ), but it still gives me the same warning.

Can someone tell me why and how to fix this?

Comment: $_GET is an array

Comment: use `filter_input` function which takes care of most use cases.

Comment: Is the php code in calculator.php or are they in the same file

Comment: `I'm not using arrays`... Do you really think PHP would be lying to you? If you looked at the line numbers of those warnings, you'd see that they point to the line involving $_GET. And then if you went to the manual for $_GET at https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php you'd see that it says that `$_GET` is "An associative array". Please, when thinking about a problem, start from the available facts rather than your own assumptions.

Comment: Anyway assuming all this code is in the same script, then the reason for your problem is probably that you're not checking whether the form has been submitted before trying to access these array elements, so probably the first time you load the page, just to display the form, it tries to access the variables but they don't exist yet (because the form hasn't been submitted). You need to be checking the `$_GET["age"]` and `$_GET["height"]` variables using `isset`, not the things you assign from there.

Comment: Also start the php code with checking if it is submited - if(isset($_GET['submit'])

Comment: @manqlele that won't work because there's no element with `name="submit"` in the form. OP could add it to the button (or elsewhere) of course, but if you wanted them to do that, you would need to have mentioned it in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

**$_GET** is an empty array on this case that's why they are undefined keys.
You should check if **$_GET** has age and height.
You can do something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['age'], $_GET['height'])){
    // do the calculation 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `extract` function.

```php
<?php
extract($_GET);
/*$age = $_GET["age"];
$height = $_GET["height"];
*/
if (isset($age) && isset($height)) {
  echo ($age + $height);
}
?>
```